# Looking of language translation API or offline options

Tags: api, translation, google-translate, microsoft-translator

I am trying to develop a java app which translates text.

My first attempt was Google Translate but it is now a paid service. 
So any other free options?

Or any offline solutions available ?

P.S. -  read somewhere that Microsoft has also made its service paid. But right now I cannot access the website to check if that is actually true. 
Thanks in advance.
And belated Merry Christmas! :) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/
Microsoft translation service: last time i checked up to 2 million chars/month free